# How to summarize multiple logical flags in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

All,
Looking for an easy way to do this. I'm pretty sure pd.groupby() could probably help me achieve this, but I am unable to get to a working example. So here is what I have:

```py
import pandas as pd 
from random import sample 

# Build a random data set 
t = [2013] *12
t1 = [2014] * 12 
t.extend(t1)
list_of_years = t
list_of_months = list(range(1, 13)) * 2 
random_data = sample(range(1, 100), 24) 
data = zip(list_of_years, list_of_months, random_data) 
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["Year", "Month", "RandomNumbers"]) 
my_df["test"] = my_df["RandomNumbers"] < 75 
my_df["test1"] = my_df["RandomNumbers"] < 50
```

So, in the above example, I have two booleans computed over each month for two years. What I would like to get is a new column where the booleans are assembled as a list for each unique month. What I am confused about is - how do you restructure this data into a new column without aggregating.

Desired Output (example):

```py
Month All_Tests
1     [True, False]
2     [False, False] 
3     [False, False]
4     [False, True]
5     [True, True]
6     [True, False]
7     [True, False]
8     [False, False] 
9     [False, True]
10    [False, True]
11    [False, True]
12    [False, True]
```

Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: There are 2 years and 2 boolean columns. Why is in output only 2 boolean, not 4 if no aggregation? Do you need processing only one column, e.g. `test` ? Or there missing column for `test1` with lists like `All_Tests`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data for testing with `seed` for same tested data:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
import pandas as pd 

# Build a random data set 
t = [2013] *12
t1 = [2014] * 12 
t.extend(t1)
list_of_years = t
list_of_months = list(range(1, 13)) * 2 
random_data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=24) 
data = zip(list_of_years, list_of_months, random_data) 
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["Year", "Month", "RandomNumbers"]) 
my_df["test"] = my_df["RandomNumbers"] < 75 
my_df["test1"] = my_df["RandomNumbers"] < 50
```

```
print (my_df)
    Year  Month  RandomNumbers   test  test1
0   2013      1             97  False  False
1   2013      2              9   True   True
2   2013      3             68   True  False
3   2013      4             68   True  False
4   2013      5             92  False  False
5   2013      6              4   True   True
6   2013      7             72   True  False
7   2013      8             57   True  False
8   2013      9             30   True   True
9   2013     10             49   True   True
10  2013     11             33   True   True
11  2013     12             25   True   True
12  2014      1             75  False  False
13  2014      2             10   True   True
14  2014      3             52   True  False
15  2014      4             12   True   True
16  2014      5             56   True  False
17  2014      6             63   True  False
18  2014      7             68   True  False
19  2014      8             70   True  False
20  2014      9             49   True   True
21  2014     10             29   True   True
22  2014     11             21   True   True
23  2014     12              9   True   True
```

If need processing only one column for multiple years:

```
df1 = my_df.groupby('Month')['test'].agg(list).reset_index(name='All_Tests')
print (df1)  
    Month       All_Tests
0       1  [False, False]
1       2    [True, True]
2       3    [True, True]
3       4    [True, True]
4       5   [False, True]
5       6    [True, True]
6       7    [True, True]
7       8    [True, True]
8       9    [True, True]
9      10    [True, True]
10     11    [True, True]
11     12    [True, True]
```

If need test if at least one `True` per years and then convert output to lists:

```
df2 = my_df.filter(like='test').groupby(my_df['Month']).any().apply(list, 1).reset_index(name='All_Tests')
print (df2) 
    Month       All_Tests
0       1  [False, False]
1       2    [True, True]
2       3   [True, False]
3       4    [True, True]
4       5   [True, False]
5       6    [True, True]
6       7   [True, False]
7       8   [True, False]
8       9    [True, True]
9      10    [True, True]
10     11    [True, True]
11     12    [True, True]
```

For convert all test columns to lists:

```
df3 = my_df.filter(like='test').groupby(my_df['Month']).agg(list).reset_index()
print (df3) 
    Month            test           test1
0       1  [False, False]  [False, False]
1       2    [True, True]    [True, True]
2       3    [True, True]  [False, False]
3       4    [True, True]   [False, True]
4       5   [False, True]  [False, False]
5       6    [True, True]   [True, False]
6       7    [True, True]  [False, False]
7       8    [True, True]  [False, False]
8       9    [True, True]    [True, True]
9      10    [True, True]    [True, True]
10     11    [True, True]    [True, True]
11     12    [True, True]    [True, True]
```